# Intercept outgoing HTTP requests to npmjs.org, etc

Tags: node.js, http, npm, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am looking to create a locally running Node.js server that can intercept outgoing requests to the NPM registry (npmjs.org, or whatever).

Is that what a reverse proxy is?

Basically what I would like to do is create a locally running NPM registry - this is for use with locally running Docker containers. Normally I would just use `npm link` for local development. But when testing libraries using Docker locally, using `npm link` for that becomes hard to impossible

I know there are some libraries out there that set up a local NPM registry, but I am looking to do this from scratch so I can set it up for my use case. Essentially I want to tarball packages that exist on my filesystem each time an `npm install` request comes in.

I started experimenting with:

```
npm config set registry http://localhost:3440
```

but when I subsequently did an `npm install`, it didn't seem to hit my locally running server, just went to `registry.npmjs.org` like normal.

I also tried modifying /etc/hosts

before:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

after:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
registry.npmjs.org localhost:3440
```

but my local server listening on port 3440 did not seem to intercept any traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's **not** a reverse proxy, but that's a **forward proxy**. And you'll effectively have to use `npm config set proxy` to use it from npm call.

The main tool used for such proxy is usually squid proxy. And I'm pretty sure you can build more robust and feature-full service using some well known forward proxy tools instead of a custom nodejs tool.

Then you'll have to check where this service is running (on the same docker? on another docker? on your host?). The address you set for npm, in `npm config set proxy` must be resolvable from inside the container running npm (but it may differ between commands running on the Dockerfile step and commands running in a bash session after that build).

Comment: thanks this helps - do you happen to understand this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341587/create-proxy-server-to-npm-registry